# Does a WebMethod always return XML?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

ASP.NET [WebMethod], does it always return XML?

I know it can only return serializable data types however can it for instance return a JSON?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I'm aware of, you can return XML or JSON.

To return JSON add this annotation or your method:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

And on your class allow `ScriptService`

```
[ScriptService]
```

An example:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public Dictionary<string, object> Test()
{
    var ret = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    ret.Add("Test", 1);
    return ret;
}

// result:
{d:{Test:1}}
```